# How to Inject CSS changes into my Electron js app?

Tags: node.js, electron, chromium, electron-builder

I use **loadURL** to load the web, I want to make some changes. Is there a way to inject a css snippet once the page is rendered?

There are extensions for chrome that do what I want (like UserCSS), but I understand that they can't be used inside an Electron App.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your page has completed loading...

Here is an example of adding CSS:

```
// When document has loaded, initialize
document.onreadystatechange = (event) => {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        // Document has finished loading here
            var styles = `img#license {
                            animation: none;
                            animation-iteration-count: 1;
                            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                            position: absolute;
                            z-index: 3;
                            width: 375px;
                            top: 204px;
                            left: 112px;
                            visibility: hidden;
                        }`
            var styleSheet = document.createElement("style");
            styleSheet.innerText = styles;
            document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
    }
};
```

I use the above to display a unlicensed image over my Electron app from the preload.js script, as it has access to the document element.

Edit the CSS to your needs.